# Wordpress - Two loops on author.php?

Tags: wordpress

Normally if I was doing more than one loop on a page, aside from the main wordpress loop, I'd just use wp_query, however when the author.php template is being used I can't see how I could use that, since I'd have to pass some args.

Pulling posts from categories or by date etc is all easy enough with wp_query, even getting posts by author ID can be done, but it needs to be generic, ie get posts from the current authors page.

Now, using the same loop as my category page I can easily generate posts on the author.php, but I need a second loop and I just can't figure out how to do it.

First loop would be pulling one random post and it's featured image, second would be getting the archive of that authors posts.

Any ideas?

Comment: A random post by the author?  Or just any old random post?

Comment: A random post by the author, getting any old random posts is easy :p

Or any post by the author for that matter, I'll work that out later, I just can't figure out how to make wp_query work on author.php to get posts by THAT author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you a list of the author's posts? If so, it should be easy to modify the arguments for WP_Query to get exactly what you want.

See here for all the options: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
<?php
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'author' => get_the_author_meta('ID')
    ) );
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
  Sorry, nothing was found.
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Nope, it displays a number at the top of each authors page (I'm assuming their ID) and the 15 latest posts on the site. This is exactly the same problem I had, getting posts of the current author with wp_query.

Comment: Did you put it inside the main Loop in the author template?

Comment: Ah, I used the wrong function - `the_author_meta()` rather than `get_the_author_meta()`.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: I did not put it inside the main loop.

Comment: It will need to go inside the loop.  Otherwise you'll need to use a different method to get the author ID.

Comment: Ah, your amendments seem to work (outside the loop), it was my understanding that you can't just be slinging loops inside each other anyway?

Comment: You can absolutely use nested loops.  That's why I'm using `$new_loop` and `wp_reset_query()`, to avoid messing with the main loop.

Comment: It's a little surprising that it works outside the loop.  I wouldn't count on that working in other contexts.

Comment: I think it works outside the loop BECAUSE it's the author.php template, in other contexts, I doubt it would yes.